# Actively Used and Developed Motion Capture Systems

Tags: motion, video-capture

I am looking for Motion Capture Systems that are actively used in the Movie Production Business.

I am currently aware of Organic Motion and it's OpenStage2 which can easily cost about 40.000$.

I would like to know if there are any alternatives that are either in the same Price-League or maybe cheaper. Most important is that it is indeed used and that it is actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

We used the [NaturalPoint OptiTrack S250e](https://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/products/s250e/) at my company for a big project that is still in active use today. We used it for a sort of game like exhibition on fairs. So it had to be quite robust and offer stable tracking in changing environments.

It is primarily used for movies and video games though. They offer quite a few different systems in price ranges [far below](https://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/products/flex-3/) your 40.000$ and [far above](https://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/products/prime-41/) that, depending on how many cameras you need and what precision you need. The prices are per camera.
They have a nice system configurator [here](http://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/systems/), which makes choosing camera count and camera system a bit easier.

Some of their bigger customers can be found [here](https://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/about/customers/). Seems like they have been proven in many bigger productions.

I have not affiliation with NaturalPoint and it's the only MotionTracking system I had contact with. There might be better solutions that I don't know of but we used their products and the result were satisfying for our special requirements.

Comment: I thank you a lot for pointing to this, this helps a lot. If it stays here as the only answer I will accept it of course.

Answer (score 0):

We use a really old Vicon system, but according to the company's [website](http://www.vicon.com/System/Bonita), new ones start at $12,500.